# How to un-nest this query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm practicing my SQL knowledge on HackerRank and I wrote a query that I feel it should't be nested but I don't know how to optimize it:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(LONG_W as numeric(16, 4)) 
FROM 
    STATION 
WHERE 
    LAT_N = (SELECT MIN(LAT_N) 
             FROM STATION 
             WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780)
```

Its weather-observation-station-17 on hackerrank. Can anyone help unnest this?

EDIT: This is from HackerRank:

Given a table STATION that holds data for five columns ID, CITY, STATE, NORTHERN LATITUDE and WESTERN LONGITUDE.

```
+-------------+------------+
| Field       |   Type     |
+-------------+------------+
| ID          | INTEGER    |
| CITY        | VARCHAR(21)|
| STATE       | VARCHAR(2) |
| LAT_N       | NUMERIC    |
| LONG_W      | NUMERIC    |
+-------------+------------+
```

Write a query to find the corresponding Western Longitude to the smallest value of the Northern Latitudes greater than 38.7780 up to 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if you are expecting only one minimum record

```
SELECT top 1 cast(LONG_W as numeric(16, 4)) FROM STATION 
WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780 order by LAT_N asc
```

Comment: not works this solution! because the original query can have more then 1 result!

Comment: @Zoneh But what if you have multiple records with the same `LAT_N`? This query won't return all of those, it will return only the first (and actually only one row all the time).

Comment: I have mentioned that in my answer the query works only if expected output is one minimum result

Comment: You're right but hackerrank accepted it because the expected output is one minimum result. It's dangerous otherwise I agree.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
DECLARE @lat INT;
SELECT @lat=MIN(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780

SELECT cast(LONG_W as numeric(16, 4)) FROM STATION 
WHERE LAT_N = @lat
```

or this

```
SELECT cast(a.LONG_W as numeric(16, 4))
FROM STATION a
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(LAT_N) LAT_N FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780) b
ON a.LAT_N = b.LAT_N
```

Comment: It still uses a nested query.